# Is this really a good question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just noticed [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24516/building-a-restaurant-site-how-should-i-implement-online-ordering) which has 5 upvotes. IMHO the question isn't really a good question since it looks pretty subjective / isn't really an question.

I'm tempting to flag it (cannot vote), but by looking at the upvotes I'm thinking I might be wrong (I don't hang out here too often).

So: Is that a valid question here on webmasters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel the same way about the question - it is subjective and is effectively polling, however, it does appear to be useful to the Webmasters community.

I have been waiting to take any action on it because a single moderator vote will effectively close the question, which is unfair to the community members who are interested in the answer - probably a good candidate for conversion to community wiki once the bounty is awarded.

**Edit:** Bounty expired without being awarded and question was converted to Community Wiki.